# Why is the function continuous, if it is defined only on integers?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Why is a function f continuous, if it is defined only on integers?

It seems very trivial but I could not find the words to describe the reason. Can smo(someone) give me a hint?

Note: there is no function. This is a verbal question. No equation exists for the function

Thanks

Comment: What function${}$?

Comment: "smo?" ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Given $f$ defined in $ \mathbb{Z} $ and given $ \epsilon> 0 $, we have that $ | f (n_1) -f (n_2) | < \epsilon $ whenever $ n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb {Z} $ are such that $ | n_1 - n_2 | < \delta $. In fact continuity follows from the fact that $ \mathbb{Z}$ and a discrete set.

Comment: @DonAntonio smo := someone.

Answer (score 6):

If $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is continuous. This is because it satisfies the definition. A function is continuous *on a certain domain*. To be honest I think it's bullshit to use this subtlety as the source of trick questions but look, this is the definition:

''A function $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x_0 \in D$ if for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x \in D$ with $|x_0 - x| < \delta$ we have $|f(x_0) - f(x)| < \epsilon$.''

The bit where is says "...for any $x$ *in* $D$..." is the important part for understanding a function defined on $\mathbb{Z}$. So for a function defined on $\mathbb{Z}$, if you take $\delta = 1$, then the only point $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ with distance less than 1 from $x_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ is $x_0$ itself. And since $|f(x_0) - f(x_0)| = 0 < \epsilon$, you have that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

If you are new to learning about continuous functions, then I think it's important to try to forget what you expect continuous functions to be and to work directly from the definition.

Comment: I think I got what you said. Since ϵ must be greater than 0 by definition, the min value ϵ can take is 1. So when we subtract a function f(a) from itself it becomes zero so it is less than 1.But, I have a question: If a function defined on integers, f(x) values take integer values as well, right?

Comment: No, it can take real values, even if its just defined on the integers. There is nothing to do with $\epsilon$ being 1 or bigger than 1. It's taking $\delta < 1$ that makes it work.